# How to implement SignalR authorisation into .Net console

Tags: c#, signalr

I have a problem with the implementation of authorization in my project.

My project is to create a program (chat) in WinForms using SignalR.
I plan to create two applications: client (WinForms) and server (Console).
I currently don't know how to implement user authorization.  I have read SignalR documentation and there is an example based on cookies. Unfortunately, I do not know how to implement it in the console because this example is in the web application. I was looking for some tips on the Internet but unfortunatelly there is almost nothing.

```
class Program
    {

            static void Main(string[] args)
            {

                string url = "http://localhost:8085";
                using (WebApp.Start<Startup>(url))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Server running on {0}", url);
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
        }
        class Startup
        {
            public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
            {
                app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
                app.MapSignalR();

            }
    }
        }
        public class MyHub : Hub
        {
            public void Send(string name, string message)
            {
                Clients.All.addMessage(name, message);
            }
        }
```

I want to add a remote login feature into the server. The problem is that I don't know how to do it from the console application level. The documentation only shows how to do this in a web application.

Comment: I assume that you use classic SignalR (not Core SignalR). [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/security/hub-authorization#authentication-options-for-net-clients) is your docs.

Comment: Thanks, I just found a man on youtube who made a console application using SignalR and Owin RestApi same time. That will help me to establish log in and create token [Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2prTfk0n9x0&list=PLXLkA7FAishpk0xVoQv7zRRf3eDKEH-qA&index=1) so now I can follow docs you provided